# How to trigger recomposition when modify the parent data using CompositionLocal

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable, compose-recomposition

when I use CompositionLocal, I have got the data from the parent and modify it, but I found it would not trigger the child recomposition.

I have successfully change the data, which can be proved through that when I add an extra state in the child composable then change it to trigger recomposition I can get the new data.

Is anybody can give me help?

### Append

code like below

```kotlin
data class GlobalState(var count: Int = 0)

val LocalAppState = compositionLocalOf { GlobalState() }

@Composable
fun App() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalAppState provides GlobalState()) {
        CountPage(globalState = LocalAppState.current)
    }
}

@Composable
fun CountPage(globalState: GlobalState) {
    // use it request recomposition worked
//    val recomposeScope = currentRecomposeScope
    BoxWithConstraints(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable {
                globalState.count++
//                recomposeScope.invalidate()

            }) {
        Text("count ${globalState.count}")
    }
}
```

I found a workaround is using `currentRecomposable` to force recomposition, maybe there is a better way and pls tell me.

Comment: @wjploop I totally understand your question. I also come from React, and in there you can do this with the Context API. I still haven't figured out how to do this with Compose. If you have, please share it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using `compositionLocalOf` in this way.

Using the State hoisting pattern you can use two parameters in to the composable:

- `value: T`: the current value to display.
- `onValueChange: (T) -> Unit`: an event that requests the value to change where T is the proposed new value.

In your case:

```
data class GlobalState(var count: Int = 0)

@Composable
fun App() {

    var counter by remember { mutableStateOf(GlobalState(0)) }
    CountPage(
        globalState = counter,
        onUpdateCount = {
                counter = counter.copy(count = counter.count +1)
            }
        )
}

@Composable
fun CountPage(globalState: GlobalState, onUpdateCount: () -> Unit) {
   
    BoxWithConstraints(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable (
                onClick = onUpdateCount
            )) {
        Text("count ${globalState.count}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply first. Forgive me didn't clearly describe my problem again. 
In my actual application,  between `App` and `CountPage`, there are many Composable. 
Adding two parameters in those Composables seems is not a good way, because those Composable don't need to know this logic (just pass state down and event up) and would add a lot of code. So I think I should use CompositionLocal.

Comment: @wjploop It is not clear what you are trying to do. In your case you should use a ViewModel, but the pattern doesn't change.

Comment: One minor nit, you should change the `var` in `GlobalState` to a `val` as `GlobalState` should be immutable.

Answer (score 6):

The composition local is a red herring here. Since `GlobalScope` is not observable composition is not notified that it changed. The easiest change is to modify the definition of `GlobalState` to,

```
class GlobalState(count: Int) {
   var count by mutableStateOf(count)
}
```

This will automatically notify compose that the value of `count` has changed.

Comment: Yes, When modifying the data provided by a CompositionLocal, Jetpack Compose doesn't automatically trigger a recomposition of its children by default. This is because CompositionLocal offers a single, shared view of the data, and changes to it wouldn't necessarily affect all child composables.

Comment: No. If you provide a different value for a composition local using `CompositionLocalProvider` it will automatically trigger recomposition. Here it was the fact the data changed was the in the object the local referred to, not the local itself. The fact the data was in a composition local was a red-herring.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your data as a `MutableState` and either provide separately the getter and the setter or just provide the `MutableState` object directly.

```kotlin
internal val LocalTest = compositionLocalOf<Boolean> { error("lalalalalala") }
internal val LocalSetTest = compositionLocalOf<(Boolean) -> Unit> { error("lalalalalala") }

@Composable
fun TestProvider(content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
  val (test, setTest) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalTest provides test,
    LocalSetTest provides setTest,
  ) {
    content()
  }
}
```

Inside a child component you can do:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Child() {
  val test = LocalTest.current
  val setTest = LocalSetTest.current

  Column {
    Button(onClick = { setTest(!test) }) {
      Text(test.toString())
    }
  }
}
```